# Invoke get-aduser from c#

Tags: c#, powershell

This is a continuation of my previous question [Invoking powershell cmdlets from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067971/invoking-powershell-cmdlets-from-c-sharp)

I want to invoke the active directory cmdlet get-aduser from within C#, and the first parameter it takes is a filter. The full cmdlet I'm trying to execute is:

```
get-aduser -filter {name -eq "joe bloggs"} -Properties * | select employeeID
```

Following from my previous question (See link above), I created a scriptblock to do that:

```
ps2.Commands.AddCommand("get-aduser");
string script = string.Format("name -eq \"{0}\"", fullname); //fullname constuction now shown
ScriptBlock filter2 = ScriptBlock.Create(script);
ps2.AddParameter("FilterScript", filter2);
ps2.AddParameter("Properties").AddArgument("*");
ps2.AddCommand("select").AddArgument("employeeID");
ps2.Invoke();
```

However, when I execute this, I get an exception at ps2.Invoke():

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'FilterScript'.

Any suggestions on this one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-ADUser doesn't have a 'FilterScript' parameter (Where-Object does), use 'Filter' :)

Comment: Great, thanks, that got me past the FilterScript problem, but now there's a new one:
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*'.
It seems the "Properties" parameter is not being accepted either :(. Sorry for being thick about this, I'm learning how to use PS through C#

Comment: Yikes, stupid mistake, fixed it now.. had to use .AddCommand("Properties","*") and not use AddArgument()