# How to list and retrieve all IIS web server instances on a network?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I wonder if it is possible with a C # application to list and retrieve all IIS instances on a connected network.

I know it is possible to recover all the instances SqlServer with

`EnumAvailableSqlServers method in the SMO`

but I do not know for IIS if it's exist a similar method . I already try to search on internet but i can not find an answer about it.

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-Service IIS* -computer ... #(all computers in the domain or on the network)
```

This is powershell though but you can execute it from C# look here : [Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments) or here : [Invoking powershell cmdlets from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067971/invoking-powershell-cmdlets-from-c-sharp)