# How to call PowerShell cmdlets from C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2012, powershell-cmdlet

I'm creating a PowerShell cmdlets from Visual Studio and I can't find out how to call cmdlets from within my C# file, or if this is even possible? I have no trouble running my cmdlets one by one, but I want to set up a cmdlet to run multiple cmdlets in a sequel.

Comment: See also [*Invoking powershell cmdlets from C#*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067971/invoking-powershell-cmdlets-from-c-sharp).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can call cmdlets from your C# code.

You'll need these two namespaces:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
```

Open a runspace:

```
Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runSpace.Open();
```

Create a pipeline:

```
Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
```

Create a command:

```
Command cmd= new Command("APowerShellCommand");
```

You can add parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Property", "value");
```

Add it to the pipeline:

```
pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
```

Run the command(s):

```
Collection output = pipeline.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
{
   ....do stuff with psObject (output to console, etc)
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Shouldn't pipeline.Commands.Add(getProcess); be pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd); - otherwise what looks like a pretty good answer.

Comment: Taught me something, anyway! Cheers -

Comment: Despite its age this is still a very helpful answer. For those using dotnet core and the CLI, begin with `dotnet add package system.management.automation` to get those namespaces.

Comment: Sorry that's not the core package, for Core you need `microsoft.powershell.sdk`

Comment: This is to run existing PowerShell cmdlets. Is there a way to run a custom cmdlet (implemented in C#) using automation API?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CliWrap Package as an alternative to [call PowerShell cmdlets from C#](https://www.byteinthesky.com/powershell/how-to-run-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-application/#using-cliwrap-package) besides using `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` and `System.Management.Automation`.

The benefit of CliWrap Package is you can interact with all external cli not only PowerShell but also Git, NPM, Docker, etc.

For example, you can try this C# code. It will retrieve all Visual Studio processes to the console as if you execute it through command line:

```
using CliWrap;
using CliWrap.Buffered;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbDailyTasks = await Cli.Wrap("powershell")
                .WithArguments(new string[] { "Get-Process", "-Name", "\"devenv\"" })
                .ExecuteBufferedAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(dbDailyTasks.StandardOutput);
            Console.WriteLine(dbDailyTasks.StandardError);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```