# Get Powershell errors from c#

Tags: c#, powershell, error-handling

**Problem**

I am invoking powershell commands from c# however, the `PowerShell` command object only seems to have the property `bool HasErrors` which doesn't help me know *what* error I received.

This is how I build my powershell command

**Library**

```
public static class PowerSheller
{
    public static Runspace MakeRunspace()
    {
        InitialSessionState session = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(session);
        runspace.Open();

        return runspace;
    }

    public static PowerShell MakePowershell(Runspace runspace)
    {
        PowerShell command = PowerShell.Create();
        command.Runspace = runspace;

        return command;
    }
}
```

**Invoking Move-Vm cmdlet**

```
using (Runspace runspace = PowerSheller.MakeRunspace())
{
    using (PowerShell command = PowerSheller.MakePowershell(runspace))
    {
        command.AddCommand("Move-VM");
        command.AddParameter("Name", arguments.VMName);
        command.AddParameter("ComputerName", arguments.HostName);
        command.AddParameter("DestinationHost", arguments.DestinationHostName);

        if (arguments.MigrateStorage)
        {
            command.AddParameter("IncludeStorage");
            command.AddParameter("DestinationStoragePath", arguments.DestinationStoragePath);
        }

        try
        {
            IEnumerable<PSObject> results = command.Invoke();
            success = command.HasErrors;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting some sort of exception to be thrown on failure, but instead it returns 0 objects. While `HasErrors` will result in knowing if the command was successful or not; I'm still not sure how to get the specific error, as no exception is thrown.

Thanks

Comment: I highly suggest such a strategy rather than doing a `ps.AddCommand(script).Invoke();` on the PowerShell handle; I had a leak or something by which with two consecutive invocations the latter would never get executed. With the runspace it works fine instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To see the errors look at the collection `PowerShell.Streams.Error` or in your code `command.Streams.Error`.

Comment: Took me a while to get back to this, had to do some other things first. For those of you who find this later. The exception thrown by the command is available in the elements in `command.Streams.Error.ElementAt(0).Exception` (assuming there is at least 1 element)

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through the `results` collection:

```
foreach (PSObject psObject in results)
{
   ....do stuff with psObject (output to console, etc... you can use ToString() if you want)
}
```

That should get you the actual output from the console.

Comment: I get 0 objects back from the call... Am I invoking the PS wrong?

Comment: @ohmusama Possibly. Take a look at the guidance I've provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264112/how-to-call-poweshell-cmdlets-from-c-sharp-in-visual-studio/21264331#21264331) on how to call PowerShell from C# and see if it works for you.