# How can I verify a Service Principal has an App role if that role is granted to a group it belongs to?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-arc

I have a group in AzureAD that contains the service principals for a group of Azure ARC servers. I also have an App Registration for an API I own and have created an app role for it called Readers. I've assigned the group to the App role and have verified that in the Azure portal.

Now when I [get a token from the Azure ARC identity endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/servers/managed-identity-authentication) for an individual service principal, the role does not appear as a claim in the token. I think this might be by design since the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-apps) say:

> Currently, if you add a service principal to a group, and then assign an app role to that group, Azure AD doesn't add the roles claim to tokens it issues.

My questions is: How do I verify that the service principal has the correct role due to its group membership? Is there some workaround I can use?

Comment: Try using Powershell. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: To be clear, I'm hoping to have a programmatic way of getting this in C# so I can verify it in my API when a request is made.

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264112/how-to-call-powershell-cmdlets-from-c-sharp-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added App role like below:

[image]

Now, I created an **Azure AD Group and added Service Principal** as member:

[image]

Assigned ***App role to the Azure AD Group***:

[image]

> My questions is: How do I verify that the service principal has the correct role due to its group membership? Is there some workaround I can use?

You can make use of below code to **fetch the app roles assigned to the Service Principal**:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Core;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string accessToken = "AccessToken";
        string servicePrincipalId = "ServicePrincipalObjID";

        var appRoles = await GetAppRolesAsync(accessToken, servicePrincipalId);

        foreach (var appRole in appRoles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"App role: " + $"{"Displayname:" + appRole.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine($" {"Value:" + appRole.Value}");
            Console.WriteLine ($" {"Id:" + appRole.Id}" );
        }
    }

    public static async Task<List<AppRole>> GetAppRolesAsync(string accessToken, string servicePrincipalId)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{servicePrincipalId}/appRoles");

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed to get app roles: {response.StatusCode}");
            }

            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
            var jsonArray = jsonObject["value"].ToString();
            var appRoles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AppRole>>(jsonArray);

            return appRoles;
        }
    }
    public class AppRole
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("allowedMemberTypes")]
        public string[] AllowedMemberTypes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("displayName")]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isEnabled")]
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The **App role assigned to the Azure AD Application with the ID displayed** successfully like below:

[image]

```cs
App role: Displayname:full_access
Value:full_access
Id: xxxxxx
```