# Consume output of a cmdlet into c# class

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Is there any way to consume the output of a cmdlet into c# code?

I have searched the web, I have mostly found topics that help writing a cmdlet but could not find anything vice versa.

Comment: i found several examples in 1 minute of searching....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some resources I was able to find via google:

- [How to run PowerShell scripts from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C)
- [Call PowerShell cmdlets from C#](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42716)
- [Invoking powershell cmdlets from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067971/invoking-powershell-cmdlets-from-c-sharp)

Hope these help.